# How do I remove the digits from the left and right side in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Originally this is what the Claim Number looks like. 000000165130 it has 12 digits. I'd like to remove the zeros on the left side and the last zero on the right side making it 16513.

select [Policy Number], left([Claim Number],11 ) [Claim Number] from DW.CLAIMDATA where [Policy Number] = 'P000463500'

```
Policy Number   [Claim Number]
P000463500      00000016513
```

But how do I remove the six zeros on the left side?

Comment: Is this always numeric and you always want to remove a trailing 0?

Comment: ^^ this... and also what would 000000165100 become?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is fixed-width, you can use `right`.

```
right(left([Claim Number],11), 5)
```

Alternately, if the number of zeros is variable, you could cast to an integer:

```
cast(left([Claim Number], 11) as int)
```

And if you need it as a string instead:

```
cast(cast(left([Claim Number], 11) as int) as varchar(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the varchar to an int, which will remove leading zeros.  it then reverses the digits and converts to an int again to remove the trailing zeros.  then just reverse on more time to get the original string without leading or trailing zeros.

```
SELECT [Policy Number]
       REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, [Claim Number])))))) [Claim Number]
FROM   DW.CLAIMDATA 
WHERE  [Policy Number] = 'P000463500'
```

Comment: Wow that is a mighty complicated way to get there.

Comment: lol.. just wanted to see if it would work..  plus there's no hard coding lengths ;)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the values are numeric AND you always have a trailing 0 you could do something like this.

```
CONVERT(INT, [Claim Number]) / 10
```